# How to display a form in popover toggle?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to display a sign in form using a popover toggle.

```
<li>
   <a href="#" rel="popup" tabindex="0" data-toggle="popover" title="SIGN IN" data-placement="bottom"  data-content='<form>
                                 <input type="text">
                              </form>
    '>Sign in</a>
</li>
```

But couldn't get it work properly. How can I achieve this?

Comment: please do not use "bootstrap" tag, use "twitter-bootstrap" as it means something else.

Comment: When you use the HTML in `data-content`, be sure to to use html entities. (`< == &lt;, > == &gt;, ect`). Also, when you initialize the popover, set the `html: true` option.

Answer (score 0):

Doc : [Bootstrap modals](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/modal.js"></script>

<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signin">

<div id="signin" class="modal hide fade" style="display: none; ">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
        <h3>Sign In</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <form action="signin.html" method="post">
            ...
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But I'm looking for the popover. Is it posssible?

Comment: My bad, I read to quickly. What's wrong with the code you tried ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the content option of javascript API instead of data-content:

```
$('#popover').popover({
    title: "Popover title",
    content: function () {
        return "<form><input type='text'></form>";
    },
    html: true
});
```

Read more about [usage](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers-usage), working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/pajusmar/ofc13kmb/).